# object junit is not a member of package org

Tags: scala, junit, sbt

When running

> sbt compile

in project root I get error:

```
object junit is not a member of package org
[error] import org.junit.Test
```

I have fully defined build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % "test"
testOptions += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.JUnit, "-q", "-v")
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0" % "test
libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % "test"
```

File TestSingleLinkedList.scala is also in project root and has:

```
import org.junit.Test
```

Comment: Do you use *junit* inside src/test?

Comment: @galando - There are many stackoverlow answers with this error - I did check each of the and at the moment - they are not applicable.  The one you provided was about putting build.sbt in the root director - I already have that.

Comment: @DraifKroneg - ok, just wanted to make sure :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems the only valid to put junit tests in sbt is:

```
├── built.sbt
├── src
│   └── test
│       └── scala
│           ├── X.scala
```

Otherwise - sbt will provide very uninformative and confusing error about junit not being included.
I found the answer from
[ScalaTest on sbt not running any tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972284/scalatest-on-sbt-not-running-any-tests)
where someone asked different question about sbt not running the tests.
In my case the sbt - was not compiling at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I made a similar mistake, trying to use Assert by importing junit in a file residing in src/main/scala.